# opengl - how to chage vertex information

Tags: opengl, glsl

I want to increase or decrease the size of the triangle.

and my verte.glsl

```c
#version 330
    
layout (location = 0) in vec3 in_Position; //--- 위치 변수: attribute position 0

uniform vec3 move;

void main(void) 
{
    gl_Position = vec4(in_Position.x + move.x, in_Position.y + move.y, in_Position.z + move.z, 1.0);
}
```

The move variable is a uniform variable that can be moved through a timer in the main program. But I don't know how to change the size of this triangle.
I think, I want to pass a new value to the `in_position` variable in the cpp file, but I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think, I want to pass a new value to the in_position variable

No. Vertices should be transformed on the GPU in the vertex shader, as you did with `move`.

---

You can scale the coordinate. Add `uniform vec3 scale` to your shader code and multiply the `in_position` by `scale`. Initialize scale with (1, 1, 1). Increase the scalars to make the triangle larger.

```c
#version 330

layout (location = 0) in vec3 in_Position;

uniform vec3 move;
uniform vec3 scale;

void main(void) 
{
    gl_Position = vec4(in_Position.xyz * scale + move, 1.0);
}
```

---

However, the usual way is not to use a [transformation](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Transformations) matrix:

```c
#version 330

layout (location = 0) in vec3 in_Position; 

uniform mat4 model_transform;

void main(void) 
{
    gl_Position = model_transform * vec4(in_Position.xyz, 1.0);
}
```

You can encode the scale, rotation and translation in 1 transformation matrix.

Comment: @백승호 1. There are 2 solutions in the answer. So use the first one. 2. You are here to learn. Now you have learned it.

Comment: Well done! Then, should the vertex information never be modified and should only be transformation??

Comment: @백승호 The vertices define the general geometry (mesh). If you only want to scale, rotate or translate the overall geometry, you should not manipulate the vertices, because it is very time-consuming to update the entire vertex buffer.  The graphics processor is designed to transform all vertices in the shortest possible time if there is a general rule (formula) that is applied to all vertices. The vertices need to be transformed in each frame anyway, for camera movement (changing the point of view) and/or animation.